# How to control Creative audio card from Windows mixer?

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, sound-card, creative

I've fitted a Creative Sound Blaster Z to my Windows 7 64-bit Professional and installed Creative control panel and (the latest 64-bit?) drivers.

In the speaker menu on the bottom right of Windows I have 2 playback devices, Speakers and SPDIF OUT, both are the Creative audio card. If I use the volume sliders in this menu nothing changes, I have to use the volume slider in the Creative control panel which is quite annoying.
The volume up/down buttons on my keyboard only affect the Windows mixer so they don't work either.

How can I configure the audio card volume to be based on what the windows mixer says so I can use the buttons on my keyboard and the sliders in Windows? Thanks

Comment: Welcome on superuser.com. Always try to make your questions as clear and concise as possible and format the text properly to make it more easily readable for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely related to: [Creative sound blaster Z windows 10 5.1 volume control](https://superuser.com/questions/1076172/creative-sound-blaster-z-windows-10-5-1-volume-control)

As solution a simple program called [Volume2](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Other-AUDIO-Tools/Volume2.shtml), that allows to set "What U Hear" as main audio device, is suggested. (But the answer is not accepted by the OP and has no up-votes.)